# How to read choiceset values in Bot dialog that are selected in Bot adaptive card using Composer dialog

Tags: botframework, bots

How to read choiceset values in Bot that are selected in Bot Adaptive Card, I am using Bot Composer to develop the Bot. I need multi select, so used Adaptive card and used send response in bot composer dialog to display the adaptive card.  But not able to read the value in subsequent actions in the dialog. Amy samples/ references based out of Bot Composer.

Comment: Please share more details - this does not look related to [tag:composer-php] to me

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed as mentioned.

You should review the response from the user in Botframework Emulator, and then inspect to see what the return values look like.

You can then retrieve it in the bot with something similar to `=turn.activity.value._answer_` (*answer* here was just a sample of what that may be. Your data will be different of course).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to save the user selection from adaptive card.
You can use **Ask a question** --> **Text** template, instead of using send response.
In **Prompt for text** section you can use HeroCard/AdaptiveCard. In **User Input** section declare a variable that will store the user selection coming from HeroCard/AdaptiveCard. Depending on the variable scope you can reuse the stored data in the variable later in the conversation.